# Is there a way we can read all files from GIT remote repository using java programming?

Tags: java, git, github

Recently I have been trying to read all files from remote GIT repository (including all branches) so that if I can find some matching string inside the files then I can retrieve information of those files like the entire line at which text is found along with file name and its path. However, I am not successful even connecting to a remote repository. I know how to search in our local directory (using a recursive function) but I want to search it from GIT remote repo only. Can someone please guide me or direct me in the right direction? I have heard about JGIT but somehow not able to follow it.

```
>   public class Git_iteration {
>  
>   
>                try         {
>            System.out.println("Try begins");
>            Repository existingRepo = new FileRepositoryBuilder()
>                       .setGitDir(new File("https://github.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/repository.git"))
>                       .build();
>            System.out.println("existing repo "+existingRepo);
> 
>               File dir = existingRepo.getDirectory();
>               System.out.println("dir "+dir);
> 
>         }          catch (Exception e)         {
>            System.out.println("Exception occoured");       }
>       
>           }
```

Above is what I tried but not able to connect to the repository at all via my IDE. I am still learning so apologies if i made some misktakes.

Comment: I can suggest using `org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git` it allows you to clone the whole repository to a local directory, then you could simply iterate over the folders and files in that directory

Comment: Is this all the code you've written? You seem to be lacking a `main()` method so that you can execute the program. Also the code you've written needs to be in a method, and not directly in the class body. Also specify what you mean with *but not able to connect to the repository at all via my IDE*

Comment: @Lino In local repository I am able to iterate but is there a way to iterate over remote GIT repository?

Comment: You `git clone` the remote repository to a local repository. The library I mentioned does that for you, that's why you're then able to iterate it

Comment: @Smith Except for `archive`/`fetch`/`pull`/`push`/`ls-remote` Git doesn't provide a way to work with remote repositories. Either you clone it locally or use other, out-of-git ways like Github/Gitlab API or any other non-git remote access like ssh or network filesystem.